# How to get USPS shipping rate in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, usps

I am using coldfusion and I want to get USPS Shipping charges in my application/website. Is there any function to get usps shipping rates from usps in coldfusion?

Comment: There is an open source project Slatwall for Mura CMS, they have used it you can browse the source code and get the help according your needs. [See](https://github.com/ten24/Slatwall/blob/master/integrationServices/usps/Shipping.cfc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First result on google for usps ColdFusion CFC  https://github.com/matthewriley/USPS-CFC

Comment: Follow the instructions listed on the site and the CFC works perfectly.

Comment: i signed up with "usps.com" and inserted username for "request.uspsUserid" for uspsCFC2 code , but it is showing  "Authorization failure" error. please suggest

Comment: Link is dead.  The [archived site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512055953/http://uspscfc.riaforge.org/) points to https://github.com/matthewriley/USPS-CFC.